# Powershell Import Excel Range to 2Dim Array

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have multiple Excel Files where have nearly the same structure:
[image]

Now I want to collect the Data reorganize it and save it to an single CSV.

How can I save the Range (A2:C12) to an 2dim Array?
2. Problem I don't know the End. But It seems to be an easy problem, because the first emtpy Cells in "A" is the last row.

My actual code:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "H:\Mailbox\08_Support\Stackoverflow\"* -Include "*.xlsx" -Recurse
$files

$Folder_OLD = ""
$csvData= @{}


#Program definieren
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
#im hintergrund ausführen
$excel.visible = $false


foreach ($file in $files)
{
$file.Name

###############
#CSV-Export
###############

if ($file.DirectoryName -ne $Folder_OLD -and $Folder_OLD -ne ""){
#DatenExportieren

#DataArray löschen
$csvData= @{}
}
##########
#Read Data
##########


$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($file)
$table = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$Range = $table.Range("A2:C12")


$ExData =  $Range | select Text
$ExData.GetType()

$Folder_OLD = $file.DirectoryName



}
$excel.Quit()
```

I tried the ImportExcel Modul but it has problems with the multiple Topic rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the Answer. just using a for loop like That:

```
$csvData = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

for ($irow=1; $irow -le ($Range.Count/3); $irow++) 
   {
   $rowdata = [pscustomobject] @{
    'B' = [STRING]""
    'C' = [STRING]""
   $rowdata.B = $Range[($irow*3)+2].Text
   $rowdata.C = $Range[($irow*3)+3].Text
   $null = $csvData.add($rowdata)

   }
```

It's not realy a 2 Dim array but an array of Objects, so you can easily export it to csv.

Comment: It looks like your solution still operates on a hard-coded range rather than determining the end of the table dynamically. Also, there appears to be no attempt to skip the header rows. It's also not clear why you're omitting the A column values from the result. In short: you're not really answering your own question.

Comment: As an aside: A much more efficient approach is to use a loop construct such as `for` as an _expression_ and let PowerShell itself collect the outputs in an array: `$csvData = for (...) { ...; $rowData <# output #> }` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375).

Answer (score 0):

> I tried the ImportExcel Module but it has problems with the multiple Topic rows.

You can still use the [`ImportExcel` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel) (which you can install with `Install-Module ImportExcel`), which is generally preferable to using the out-of-process, Windows-only, slow Excel COM Automation interface you're using.

Given that the *header* rows (which you call *Topic* rows) in the data in your spreadsheet all start with the same header name, `Nr`, it's easy to filter them out:

```bash
$csvData = 
  Import-Excel $file -DataOnly -HeaderName A, B, C | 
  Where-Object 'A' -ne 'Nr'

# If you don't care about column A on exporting to a CSV, pipe to 
# Select-Object; e.g.:
#  $csvData | Select-Object B, C | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation out.csv
```

- `-DataOnly` imports "only rows and columns that contain data".
- `-HeaderName A, B, C` specifies header names for the imported data, which become the *property names* for the `[pscustomobject]`s that are emitted (see next point).

  - It looks like the module employs *heuristics* in order to *infer* whether the first row in the data represents a header row or not, based on whether subsequent rows are substantially different (I don't know how that's determined).
  - The `-HeaderName` argument either *overrides* a preexisting header row or *provides one that may be missing* from the data.

    - Only as many columns as are passed to `-HeaderName` are retrieved from the data, however; e.g., `-HeaderName A, B, C` retrieves only *three* column values from each data row.
    - If you don't know the number of columns ahead of time, you can use the `-NoHeader` switch, allowing you to retrieve an *open-ended* number of columns, which will be named `P1`, `P2`, ...

      - However, note that the heuristic is then *bypassed*, meaning that the first row is invariably treated as *data*.
- The above outputs `[pscustomobject]` instances with property names `.A`, `.B`, and `.C`, each containing the (first) 3 column values of each *data* row and stores them in `$csvData`.